# how to check the stability of t-SNE?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, tsne, manifold-learning

I am looking some technique that help us to test the stability of t-SNE for different times running.

Comment: Can please tell  what is t-SNE?

Comment: t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding